# Test the context of a method call using sinonjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I have a class where I bind a method on initialization  as follows -

```
function MyClass() {
    this.onHttpCallback = _.bind(onHttpCallback, this);
}

function onHttpCallback(){
   //... 
}
```

How do I test if the `onHttpCallback` when called, is always called with an object of MyClass as context?

I am using sinon.js to mock and the following code doesn't work -

```
it('should be binded', function () {
    //ctrl is an object of MyClass
    var dummy_obj = {};
    var spy = sinon.spy(ctrl.onHttpCallback);
    spy.call(dummy_obj);
    spy.alwaysCalledOn(ctrl).should.be.ok;
});
```

**Update**
As per the comments in the following answer, it seems like it is impossible to test the binding for a method.

**My Take on the problem**

```
//Source.js

function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.prototype.init = function(){
   this.onHttpCallback = _.bind(MyClass.onHttpCallback, this);
}


MyClass.onHttpCallback(){
   //... 
}

//Test.js

it('should bind onHttpCallback', function () {
    sinon.spy(_, 'bind');
    ctrl.init();
    _.bind.calledWith(ctrl.constructor.onHttpCallback, ctrl).should.be.ok;
    _.bind.restore();
});
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: You are calling the spy with `dummy_obj` as `this` so obviously `this` will not be `ctrl`. Am I missing something? Is the problem that you expect that `this` cannot be changed after using `_.bind`?

Comment: You've got it alright. I basically want to test that no matter how I call the `onHttpCallback` method, the context should always be `ctrl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you wonder why `this` changes even though you clearly bound it to be `MyClass` before, that's because you use `call` with `dummy_obj` on the spy.
The spy wraps the original function, so it has no concept of that function's binding. It will still accept a different binding on the wrapper function, then try to call the original with that `this`, which is then ignored by the original function.

```
var context = {foo: 'bar'};
var original = _.bind(function () { console.log(this); }, context);
var spy = function (original) {
    var spyFn = function () {
        var _this = this;
        spyFn.calledOn = function (ctx) { return ctx === _this; };
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    return spyFn;
};
var originalSpy = spy(original);
// Will call the spyFn with a different `this`, but will not affect the original binding
originalSpy.call({something: 'else'});
>> {foo: 'bar'}
// Since the spy cannot know the original binding, it will think the assumption is false.
originalSpy.calledOn(context) === false;
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Is it not implemented in sinon by default? I mean, isn't it a common use case?

Comment: It's pretty much impossible, since `bind` is basically another wrapper which lies one layer below the spy. You'd have to spy on the function that you are binding. 
I think this kind of test is overtesting. You should trust that underscore's tests for the `_.bind` method are passing and not bother with checking it again yourself. Better test the actual functionality.  It's more important that the `onHttpCallback` function does the right things to whatever `this` you are passing it. For that, you will have to expose it including a way to set its this binding manually.

Comment: I guess you are right, for now I will leave it then :(

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I am waiting for someone else also to take a look at the question once.

Comment: You can see in https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/blob/7eaf783f1a2265a5a1113d77da0f70faf4ac96a7/lib/sinon/spy.js#L82 that it takes the `this` value you call the function spy with. What goes on inside is not really possible to tell if the function is bound.